# Swift:fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value In dispatch_async dispatch_get_global_queue

Tags: swift

I have table view in which i am showing 3 cell,and depends upon the collection view cell which is working as like paging. So When i want to get the image on table view cell from `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue...)` some time i got the

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My Code is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.videoTableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customTableViewCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

    let videoDataObj:VideoData  = subVideoArray .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! VideoData
    cell.titleLabel.text        = videoDataObj.videoTitle as String
    cell.descLabel.text         = videoDataObj.videoDesc  as String
    cell.playButton.tag         = indexPath.row + (pageIndex * noOfElement)

    let imageUrl =  NSURL(string: videoDataObj.videoImage as String)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)){
        let data    =   NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl!)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            cell.videoImageView?.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
            cell.videoImageView?.image   =   UIImage(data: data!)

            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        }

    return cell

}
```

Screen Shot Of View Is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U4qZ.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: **Never** use `NSData(contentsOfURL: )` to load data from the network, not even in asynchronously dispatched queues. Look at Apple's [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) how to load data lazily into a table view

Comment: Thanks a lot for your sujjession vadian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes !!! I review my code and got solution. I was doing the silly mistake.
Try it..
Updated Code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)){

        if let data  = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl!){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                cell.videoImageView?.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
                cell.videoImageView?.image   =   UIImage(data: data)

                cell.setNeedsLayout()
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            })

        }
```